# Tailwind Container Not Working at SM Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

this is my first time to using tailwind
But i got some problem to build a responsive website
The container is not working at Small devices
It works at Medium devices like this: [Medium Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnp8c.png) 
And this one is at Small devices: [Small Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEBZ2.png) 
There is the code:

```
    <div className="bg-blackColor min-h-screen">
      <div className="container mx-auto py-10">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex flex-[2_2_0%] items-center justify-between">
            <div className="flex-1">
              <img src={EnverLogo} alt="Logo" className="w-[130px] h-[40px]" />
            </div>
            <ul className="lg:flex justify-between flex-1 hidden">
              <li className="text-lg font-bold hover:text-whiteColor text-primaryColor">Home</li>
              <li className="text-lg text-opacity-70 hover:text-opacity-100 text-whiteColor">Services</li>
              <li className="text-lg text-opacity-70 hover:text-opacity-100 text-whiteColor">Our Project</li>
              <li className="text-lg text-opacity-70 hover:text-opacity-100 text-whiteColor">About Us</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="lg:flex flex-1 items-center justify-end hidden">
            <div className="w-[160px] h-[35px] border-2 border-whiteColor rounded-md backdrop-blur-md" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Comma, welcome to SO. In order to assist you will need to provide a bit more details in your question. What do you mean by "The container is not working at Small devices" Can you try and create a create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can pinpoint exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi Daniel, the container utilities is not working on small screen...

Comment: Yes you need to explain what do you mean it is not working on a small screen. Is everything too large, is nothing showing, is it not responsive? What should it look like. Once you have done that try and remove items from your html from the middle until you get to the line where it gets working correctly. I.e. does `<div className="bg-blackColor min-h-screen"></div>` look correct. This is what I mean by Minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're wondering why there is no horizontal padding on the small screen. This is because below `sm`, the width is 100% so of course it would span the entire viewport width. On `sm` and up, it would look like there is padding because the viewport might be a little larger than `640px` and you might have centered it.

If my assumption is correct, you would need to manually provide padding to the container yourself as per [Tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container#adding-horizontal-padding):

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: '1rem',
        sm: '2rem',
        lg: '4rem',
        xl: '5rem',
        '2xl': '6rem',
      },
    },
  },
};
```